# No overflow error at compile time when int.MaxValue assigned to a variable

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, I understand that the following code will fail because of integer overflow:

```
int max = int.MaxValue + 1; // error CS0220: The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode
```

But then, why the following C# code does not fail at compile time and just warp around?

```
int max = int.MaxValue;
int res = max + 1; // -2147483648
```

Comment: The C# compiler evaluates *constant expressions* at compile-time.  Using a variable instead of constants makes it incapable of seeing the overflow, you have to use `checked`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not do in-depth analysis to detect any possible outcome where an integer variable could overflow. The first example is fairly obvious - the second needs to analyze two different lines of code to detect the overflow, which the compiler is not designed to do.

From the [documentation for the `checked` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) (emphasis added):

> By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type. **If the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow**.

Comment: I get it. Make total sense. Thank you very much. 

Also, Into @wesley-santos link there is a explanation for the integral-type checking: _By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow_

Comment: Good catch. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly enabled overflow checking with [checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) keyword.

Comment: `checked` is for _runtime_ detection, not _compile-time_.